# media query not working on android emulator

Tags: android, cordova, media-queries, nexus-4

I'm working on a phonegap app and trying to test it on android emulators. 
The emulator that I'm testing on is Nexus 4. 
Here is the media query that I'm using:

@media screen and (device-width: 384px) and (device-height: 592px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  //my css styles
  //nothing works here

}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout, do you have this code in your template:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And as I know, Nexus don't have Retina, so you should remove:

```
-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2
```

from your media-queries

Comment: I have that meta tag. But it still doesn't work even after I removed webkit-device-pixel-ratio.